# Mask raster time series

Tags: raster, extract-by-mask

I am quite new on spatial R. I would like to apply the land mask to monthly SST data from https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/gridded/data.noaa.oisst.v2.highres.html.
I tried to use "mask" from the raster package but the output raster (NoLand) is missing the Z (Date).

```
nc = raster("N:/Papier DLM/sst_extraction.nc")
mask = raster("N:/Papier DLM/lsmask.nc")
mask2 <- crop(mask,extent(nc))
NoLand<-mask(nc, mask2)
writeRaster(NoLand, "N:/Papier DLM/NoLand.nc")
```

What should I use to apply the mask over time (for each month)?